# BadTokenException when call alertdialog in ValueEventListener onDataChange

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@e95f236 is not valid; is your activity running?

Use alertdialog in the Firebee event listener as shown below.

Often an error occurs in the listener.

```
private ValueEventListener mInviteListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            String token = (String) dataSnapshot.getValue();
            if (token != null) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                builder.setMessage("accep??");
                builder.setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        ownerLayoutShowHide(OwnerStatus.INIT);

                    }
                });
                builder.setNegativeButton("no", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                                }
                });
                builder.setCancelable(false);
                mInvitationAlertDialog = builder.create();

                if (!mInvitationAlertDialog.isShowing()) {
                    mInvitationAlertDialog.show();
                }


            } else {
                //none
            }

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
};
```

Comment: You have posted both a problem and a solution.  So what is your question?

Comment: Sorry. I have posted to share information, but I'll be careful from now on.

Answer (score 0):

Your activity is not attached that's why its throwing bad token exception.
Check activity is not null

Comment: Yes =>  MainActivity.this != null && !MainActivity.this.isFinishing()

Comment: Try like this, getActivity() != null && getActivity.isFinishing()

Comment: @ShiningChoi If its worked then please accept answer so that it will help to others